# Do hold notes count towards completion percentage?

Tags: hatsune-miku-project-diva-mega-mix

In Hatsune Miku: Project DIVA Mega Mix, if I hit a hold note but I don't hold down the button for the full amount of bonus points, will that impact my completion percentage shown at the end of the song?

Comment: I think releasing too early counts as a *bad* note, but that might be the other Project Diva games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Unlike Hold Notes in previous Project Diva games, you don't need to hold the entire slider from end to finish to count, you just need to hit it at the beginning. Completing the slider just gives you an extra percentage, like Hold Bonusses.